# Computed Column in SQL vs Inline Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to know how the performance is affected when I use a computed column and when I use an inline logic.

For example, when I use

```
SELECT [ColA], [ColB], [ColA]/[ColB] AS [ColC] FROM [Table1]
```

And when I use computed column

```
ColC as ColA/ColB
```

Comment: I think they both are same. there is no difference,

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans of two queries. Inline will take lesser resource than Computed Column

Comment: There is no way to learn 10000 "rules" about performance and then always write code that performs the absolute best. The best way to think about performance is to ignore it, unless or until you have an actual performance *issue* (whether that's a real issue or a synthetic one caused by measurement against some concrete goals), then determine *what* is causing you performance problems and then concentrate your efforts there (say, as in the above, by trying both out in your *actual* queries with your *actual* data).

Comment: In this case both are just fine.  Do what makes the most sense to you until you have an actual performance issue and then test with you data.

Comment: Just to corroborate what others are saying, let's say that you end up having a perf problem and the calculated column is the way to go. Once you implement it, the optimizer is smart enough to use it in cases where you're asking for the expression that defines the calculated column. So, in your example, if you do `select colA/colB`, the optimizer knows that colC is defined as exactly that and will use it. There's no need to change your code/query.

Comment: Thanks Guys! 
Will test it out with both queries.

Comment: @BenThul You don't by chance have a reference to SQL Server documentation that explains this? I was surprised to see a large insertion script perform better with an extra index, but in addition to the index we've added a computed column which the index is based on. Several queries are based on this computed expression so it sort of make sense, but I don't know for sure how this mechanism works or how it can be relied upon.

Comment: I don't, but you should be able to look at an execution plan and see if it's calculating an expression or if it's reading data. I'll look a little bit later and if I find something, I'll let you know.